# 'more smooth' or 'more smoother'? Which is right?

Tags: word-usage, comparison

> Curve A is more smooth than curve B

Should 'smooth' be replaced by 'smoother'?

Comment: Grammatically, the most correct form is 'smoother'. It's a monosyllabic word, just as fast -> faster, quick -> quicker, etc. NOTE: when smooth is used as an adverb, it may become 'more smoothly' E.g. with the friction taken out, the wheel rolled more smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

You can say "more smooth", or "smoother". Both are fine and mean exactly the same thing.

But beware of trying to combine them, and saying "more smoother"! Many will say that a formulation like that is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

While 'smoother' and 'more smooth' can be understood the same, 'smoother' has been way more popular.
[image: Google Ngram Viewer]